# Python: How to sort the alphabet in a list without sorted functions?

Tags: python, string, list, sorting, alphabetical

This is not based on efficiency, and has to be done with only a very very basic knowledge of python (Strings, Tuples, Lists basics) so no importing functions or using sort/sorted. (This is using Python 2.7.3).

For example I have a list:

```
unsort_list = ["B", "D", "A", "E", "C"]
sort_list = []
```

sort_list needs to be able to print out:

```
"A, B, C, D, E"
```

I can do it with numbers/integers, is there a similar method for alphabetical order strings? if not what would you recommend (even if it isn't efficient.) without importing or sort functions.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm. Selection or bubble are easiest to implement.

Comment: It's your homework, it's yours to do!

Comment: If you can do it with numbers, you can do it for strings without any change in your code. In python you can compare strings using `<`, `>` etc. just like numbers.

Comment: Ascii character codes are organized such that `ord("A") < ord("B") < ord("C") ...`, `ord()` being the ordinal function. If there is a one-to-one mapping between integers and strings, then you can use the exact same algorithm to sort letters as you can numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a very short implementation of the [Quicksort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort) algorithm in Python:

```
def quicksort(lst):
    if not lst:
        return []
    return (quicksort([x for x in lst[1:] if x <  lst[0]])
            + [lst[0]] +
            quicksort([x for x in lst[1:] if x >= lst[0]]))
```

It's a toy implementation, easy to understand but too inefficient to be useful in practice. It's intended more as an academic exercise to show how a solution to the problem of sorting can be written concisely in a functional programming style. It will work for lists of [comparable](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__cmp__) objects, in particular for the example in the question:

```
unsort_list = ['B', 'D', 'A', 'E', 'C']
sort_list   = quicksort(unsort_list)

sort_list
> ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']
```

Comment: filter + lambda? Not sure I like this.

Comment: @thg435 ok, me neither. I changed it to use comprehensions

Answer (score 1):

just for fun:

```
from random import shuffle
unsorted_list = ["B", "D", "A", "E", "C"]

def is_sorted(iterable):
  for a1,a2 in zip(iterable, iterable[1:]):
     if a1 > a2: return False
  return True

sorted_list = unsorted_list
while True:
   shuffle(sorted_list)
   if is_sorted(sorted_list): break
```

the average complexity should be factorial and the worst case infinite

Comment: Well, really slow tho :-)

Answer (score 1):

Python already know which string is first and which is next depending on their ASCII values

for example:

```
"A"<"B"
 True
```

so we can write a simple bubble sort algorithm to sort the list of strings

```
unsort_list = ["B", "D", "A", "E", "C"]
def sortalfa(unsort_list):
    for i in range(len(unsort_list)-1):
        for j in range(i+1,len(unsort_list)):
            if unsort_list[i]>unsort_list[j]:
                temp = unsort_list[i]
                unsort_list[i] = unsort_list[j]
                unsort_list[j] = temp
    print("sorted list:{}".format(unsort_list))

sortalfa(["B", "D", "A", "E", "C"])
```

Result:

```
sorted list:['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']
```

There are many standard libraries available by which can be done using single line of code.

Answer (score 0):

```
u = ["B", "D", "A", "E", "C"]
y=[]
count=65
while len(y)<len(u):
    for i in u:
        if ord(i)==count:
            y.append(i)
            count+=1
print(y)
```

Comment: This code will lead to infinite loop when u will contain non contiguous elements, e.g. when u = ["B", "D", "A", "F", "C"]. The reason is that count starts with 65 which corresponds to ascii value of "A" and is incremented for every next value present in the array. After D is found in the given list, it will not be able to find "E" and so the check ord("G") == 68 will never give True result and hence it will lead to infinite loop because len(y) will never reach len(u)

Answer (score 0):

This uses only the `min()` built-in and `list` object methods:

```
unsort_list = ["B", "D", "A", "E", "C"]
sort_list = []

while unsort_list:
    smallest = min(unsort_list)
    sort_list.append(smallest)
    unsort_list.pop(unsort_list.index(smallest))

print sort_list
```

It destroys the unsorted list, so you might want to make a copy of it and use that.

Answer (score 0):

list_val=['c','d','e','a','r']

```
for passnum in range(len(list_val)-1, 0, -1):
  for i in range(passnum):
    if list_val[i] > list_val[i+1]:
      list_val[i], list_val[i+1] = list_val[i+1], list_val[i]
```

print list_val

Answer (score 0):

The [`more_itertools`](https://github.com/erikrose/more-itertools) library has an implementation of a mergesort algorithm called [`collate`](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#more_itertools.collate).

```
import more_itertools as mit

iterables = ["B", "D", "A", "E", "C"]
list(mit.collate(*iterables))
# ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried something like this but I'm not sure about time complexity of program.

```
l=['a','c','b','f','e','z','s']
l1=[]
while l:
    min=l[0]
    for i in l:
        # here **ord** means we get the ascii value of particular character.
        if ord(min)>ord(i):
            min=i
     l1.append(min)
     l.remove(min)
print(l1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
def quicksort(lst):
    if not lst:
        return []
    return (quicksort([x for x in lst[1:] if x <  lst[0]])
            + [lst[0]] +
            quicksort([x for x in lst[1:] if x >= lst[0]]))
unsort_list = ['B', 'D', 'A', 'E', 'C']
sort_list   = quicksort(unsort_list)
```

sort_list

> ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']

Answer (score 0):

```
def insertion_sort(array):
mapped = len(array)
for i in range(1, mapped):
    indexi = array[i]
    indexj = i - 1
    while indexj >= 0 and indexi < array[indexj]:
        array[indexj+1] = array[indexj]
        indexj = indexj - 1
    array[indexj+1] = indexi

#driver or execution code
a = [2,3,5,7,1,4,6]
insertion_sort(a)
print(a)
b = ['B', 'D', 'A', 'E', 'C']
insertion_sort(b)
print(b)
```

#Result

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']
```

Answer (score -1):

even simpler:

```
dc = { }
for a in unsorted_list:
  dc[a] = '1'

sorted_list = dc.keys()
```

Comment: this works only for `int` because in this case the hash is the `int` itself

Answer (score -1):

```
u = ["B", "D", "A", "F", "C"]

y=[]

count=65

while len(y)<len(u):

    for i in u:

        if ord(i)==count:

            y.append(i)

    count+=1

print(y)
```

Comment: This would be a better answer if you explained how the code you provided answers the question.