# Need to reorder list and make a sentence in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, sorting, alphabetical, sentence

I need help rearranging this list alphabetically

```
list= ['z', 'a', 'b', 'y', 'c', 'x', 'd', 'w', 'e', 'v', 'f', 'g', 'u', 'h', 'i', 'j', 't' ,'k', 'l', 's', 'm', 'n', 'r', 'o', 'p', 'q', ' ']
```

into "hello world" by indexing into the array. How exactly do I do that? I'm a beginner and I'm doing this in python 2.7.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python: How to sort the alphabet in a list without sorted functions?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13101468/python-how-to-sort-the-alphabet-in-a-list-without-sorted-functions)

Comment: Don't call it `list` though, or you'll mask the built-in function `list()`.

Comment: What do you mean by "into 'hello world'"?

Comment: ```How exactly do I do that?``` - Go through [the Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html), trying all the examples, till you think you have learned enough to attempt a solution.  Maybe try other tutorials also.  Actually trying the examples is the key.

Answer (score 0):

As has been mentioned, your list can be sorted alphabetically by using the sort() function as follows:

```
mylist = ['z', 'a', 'b', 'y', 'c', 'x', 'd', 'w', 'e', 'v', 'f', 'g', 'u', 'h', 'i', 'j', 't' ,'k', 'l', 's', 'm', 'n', 'r', 'o', 'p', 'q', ' ']
mylist.sort()
print mylist
```

Which results in your list looking like:

```
[' ', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']
```

But you go on to say 'index into' for 'hello world'. If you mean you want to create a simple cypher then this could be easily be achieved as follows:

```
import string

s_from = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz '
s_to = 'zabycxdwevfguhijtklsmnropq '
cypher_table = string.maketrans(s_from, s_to)
print "hello world".translate(cypher_table)
```

This would convert your text as follows:

```
wcggi rikgy
```

Please could you edit your question to give an example of what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Since there is a empty element in the list. You can try to avoid them by using sorted method of list

```
>>> sorted(list_alphabet, key=list_alphabet.remove(' '))
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']
```

sorted does create new copy of actual list and sort them. So you can refer the output of the sorted to new variable. Like

```
>>> sorted_list_alphabet = sorted(list_alphabet, key=list_alphabet.remove(' '))
>>> sorted_list_alphabet
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']
```

PS: do not use list as a variable name because it brings conflict between actual list and your list variable