# Function for Sorting a List of Strings: Output for lower method not in lower case

Tags: python

So, I have this homework problem where I have create a function that sorts a list of strings into alphabetical order. However, I cannot use the sorted function or the sort method. I am trying to achieve this by converting the strings into ASCII code and sorting them from least to greatest. However, in ASCII, uppercase letters always come first, so I am trying to convert the uppercase letters into lowercase letters. I am able to create a list of lowercase letters, but for some reason when I pass it through the function, it still reads the upper case letters and sorts the list that way. What mistake am I making?

```
lst = ['Hello', 'pot', 'House', 'take', 'prime']
no_caps_list = []
i = 0
m = 0
ascii_list, sorted_ascii_list, new_list = [], [], [];
length_new_list = len(new_list)

print(lst)

def NoCaps(lst):
    length = len(lst)
    for i in range(0,length):
        no_caps_list.append(lst[i].lower())
        i = i + 1
    return no_caps_list

NoCaps(lst)
print(no_caps_list)
length = len(no_caps_list)

def CreateAscii(no_caps_list):
    m = 0
    for i in range(0,length):
        ascii_list.append(ord(no_caps_list[i][m]))
        i = i + 1
    return(ascii_list)

CreateAscii(lst)
print(ascii_list)

length_ascii = len(ascii_list)

def SortAsciiList(ascii_list):
    for i in range(0,length_ascii):
        lowest = min(ascii_list)
        sorted_ascii_list.append(lowest)
        ascii_list.remove(lowest)
    return sorted_ascii_list

SortAsciiList(ascii_list)

print(sorted_ascii_list)

length_SAL = len(sorted_ascii_list)

for i in range(0,length_SAL):
    lm = chr(sorted_ascii_list[i])
    print(lm)
    i = i + 1
```

I expect to have

```
['Hello', 'pot', 'House', 'take', 'prime']
['hello', 'pot', 'house', 'take', 'prime']
[104, 112, 104, 116, 112]
[104, 104, 112, 112, 116]
h
h
p
p
t
```

Instead, I got:

```
['Hello', 'pot', 'House', 'take', 'prime']
['hello', 'pot', 'house', 'take', 'prime']
[72, 112, 72, 116, 112]
[72, 72, 112, 112, 116]
H
H
p
p
t
```

Comment: You're passing `lst` to `CreateAscii`. I think you want to pass `no_caps_list`.

Comment: Just an observation, but I think you're misunderstanding how globals/return values work. Your functions return values, but modify globals and the return values are ignored. You also name your function parameters the same as globals, which is bound to get confusing!

Comment: In for i in range(0,length), why are you incrementing i (i.e. have i = i + 1)?

Comment: Example of sorting [without using sort functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13101468/python-how-to-sort-the-alphabet-in-a-list-without-sorted-functions).  See the first answer (uses quicksort).  A simpler option is to [code bubble sort](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-program-for-bubble-sort/)