# Sorting Words Into the Alphabetic Order in Python

Tags: python, sorting

I am trying to write a python code that can sort lowercase words in the order of the dictionary.  Firstly sort the words by the first letter, if the first letter is the same, then compare the second letter, and so on. After sorting, print out the words in the sorted order, separated by commas. The inputed words needs to be seperated with commas aswell.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you provide some concrete data?

Comment: Why would you not use the `sort` function?  This is exactly what it is there for.

Comment: Use `list.sort` or `sorted` to sort the strings. It can do custom sorts, but sorting strings in lexicographical order is the default, so no need for anything fancy. If the input is a single string that contains comma, use `str.split(',')` to split on the commas. For instance, `sorted('hello,hi,allo,albatros,yellow,hiello'.split(','))` returns the list of strings `['albatros', 'allo', 'hello', 'hi', 'hiello', 'yellow']`

Answer (score 1):

I think there is part of this question is already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13101468/python-how-to-sort-the-alphabet-in-a-list-without-sorted-functions). but I'll post the code that should answer your question completely.

```
def quicksort(lst):
    if not lst:
        return []
    return (quicksort([x for x in lst[1:] if x <  lst[0]])
            + [lst[0]] +
            quicksort([x for x in lst[1:] if x >= lst[0]]))

s = "I am trying to write a python code that can sort lowercase words in the order of the dictionary"
s = s.lower().split()
print(s)
arr = s
print("Sorted array is:", quicksort(arr))
```

Comment: An explanation of how this works would be nice!

Comment: @NoahBroyles I encourage you to check the implementation of the [Quicksort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort) algorithm in Python. I got the code from the link I mentioned in the post. I am using lower() to change the characters in the string to lowercase and then split them with "," and put them in the list. Later, I just pass it to the function, which takes care of sorting.

Answer (score 0):

If your dictionnary is actually a Python list containning words we can sort it directly. If it is a Python dictionnary a direct sort will sort by the keys and we need to use a lambda function to sort by the values.

```
words = ['yes','no','black','white']
print("# unsorted list")
print(words)
words.sort()
print("# sorted list")
print(words)
print('')

frenchWords={'yes':'oui','no':'non','black':'noire','white':'blanc'}
print("# unsorted dictionnary")
print(frenchWords)

print("# default dictionnary sort")
for i in sorted (frenchWords):
  print((i, frenchWords[i]))
  
print("# dictionnary keys sorted")
for i in sorted (frenchWords.keys()):
  print(i)

print("# dictionnary sorted by values")  
print(sorted(frenchWords.items(), key = lambda kv:(kv[1], kv[0])))
```

output

```
# unsorted list
['yes', 'no', 'black', 'white']
# sorted list
['black', 'no', 'white', 'yes']
# unsorted dictionnary
{'yes': 'oui', 'no': 'non', 'black': 'noire', 'white': 'blanc'}
# default dictionnary sort
('black', 'noire')
('no', 'non')
('white', 'blanc')
('yes', 'oui')
# dictionnary keys sorted 
black
no
white
yes
# dictionnary sorted by values
[('white', 'blanc'), ('black', 'noire'), ('no', 'non'), ('yes', 'oui')]
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe try converting to ASCII using ord(), and then perform a stable sort such as [radix sort](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/radix-sort/)